# Xfce window manager forget Super-D keyboard shortcut when I use setxkbmap

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, setxkbmap

I'm running Linux Mint 20 with the Xfce desktop environment. As I am used to hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for minimizing all windows, I changed the shortcut from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Settings / Window Manager / Keyboard. It works perfectly.

Then a few minutes later, I run the `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` command at the terminal to make <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> act like a <kbd>Control</kbd> key. After that, the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut doesn't work anymore. It's still listed in Settings / Window Manager / Keyboard but hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> just types a <kbd>D</kbd>. If I edit the shortcut and set it to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> again, it works again.

Why does this happen, and how can I make the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut permanent?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer. When I added the <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut for "Show desktop" by clicking on the Edit button, that didn't remove the previous shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> but rather added a new shortcut (the previous shortcut is not shown in the list, which made me think it was replaced by my shortcut).

When I clicked on "remove" to remove the <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut, the previous <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> reappeared out of nowhere! So I removed that one and then re-added the <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut. Everything has been working fine since then.

It seems that the bug is a combination of two things:

1. When editing a shortcut, the previous shortcut is silently kept but not shown in the list.
2. Invoking the setxkbmap command preserves only the first shortcut and not the second one (which is the one shown in the list).

Comment: This answer solves any "forgotten shortcut" problems. Clear shortcut before replacing it.